# Finding locations where two strings differ

Tags: python, string, algorithm, pattern-matching, nltk

I have two extremely long sequences of words.

I need to find places where they differ. For example, if the input is

```
1st sequence: A B C D E F G
2nd sequence: A X D Y Z W G
```

(each character here represents a word)

The output should be:

```
B C -> X
E F -> Y Z W
```

What I have thought of: I could have an index to both sequences. Initially, both would point to A. Increment both indices. Now the first index points to B and the second to X. I could now search the entire second sequence for B. Not finding it, I could search the entire second sequence for C, and then for D. I would find a D, and could hence solve the problem.

Obviously, this 'brute force' method is terrible.

What is a better method?

I am writing my code in Python, and using NLTK, so if this can be solved partially or completely using in-built NLTK functionality, it would be faster (to implement).

Comment: Longest common subsequence might be more applicable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`difflib.SequenceMatcher.get_opcodes` can do this.

```
import difflib

def diff(a, b):
    for tag, i1, i2, j1, j2 in difflib.SequenceMatcher(a=a, b=b).get_opcodes():
        if tag!='equal':
            yield a[i1:i2], b[j1:j2]

>>> d = list(diff('A B C D E F G'.split(), 'A X D Y Z W G'.split()))
>>> d
[(['B', 'C'], ['X']), (['E', 'F'], ['Y', 'Z', 'W'])]
>>> '\n'.join('{} -> {}'.format(*(' '.join(i) for i in l)) for l in d)
B C -> X
E F -> Y Z W
```

---

Old answer – an equivalent function:

```
import difflib

def diff(a, b):
    add, remove = [], []
    for line in difflib.ndiff(a, b):
        d, line = line[0], line[2:]
        if d in '+-':
            (add if d=='+' else remove).append(line)
        elif add or remove:
            yield remove, add
            add, remove = [], []
    if add or remove:
        yield remove, add
```

Comment: That certainly solves the problem! Thanks! If I need to find out what algorithm difflib uses internally, I'll look up their documentation.

Answer (score 1):

This is the classic edit-distance problem. I'm just going to let you google it and understand how it works. No need for reps on this one.

Comment: NLTK has functionality to find the edit-distance. The problem is - that's just a numerical measure of the similarity between two strings. I just obtained a Levenstein distance of 34 between my two 'test' strings. However, I need the actual differences and their locations, not just a number!

Comment: You can easily modify the edit distance question to give you the actual changes that you have to make.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the pseudocode example on the [Levenstein distance wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance#Computing_Levenshtein_distance). This example can be easily modified to suit your needs.